# sql function that can see, and aggregate, differences between two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

I have a table like this:

```
create table Stuff
(StuffID int identity not null,
 StuffPrice decimal (8,2) not null,
 StuffSold decimal (8,2) not null,
 StuffPriceTime datetime not null)
```

I'd like to do a query that shows, for the recordset I'm returning, the number of times that StuffPrice was greater than StuffSold. Is there any SQL batch way of doing this? Something like:

```
Select
 StuffID,
 StuffPrice,
 StuffSold,
 StuffPriceTime,
 SomeFunction(StuffPrice,StuffSold)
From Stuff
```

Where I'd see a resultset that looks something like:

```
[StuffID] - [StuffPrice] - [StuffSold] - [StuffPriceTime] - [True/False Result]
```

Now that I'm writing this out, I suppose I could do a UDF scalar function but I've heard the performance can be terrible for those.

Comment: Regarding the aggregating part, if the true/false comes back as a 0/1 I can just SUM().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, any kind of difference between the columns that can be presented as logical expression (predicate) can be expressed as flag - `CASE WHEN predicate=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` and then summarized to the final result.

For example:

```
create table Stuff
(StuffID int identity not null,
 StuffPrice decimal (8,2) not null,
 StuffSold decimal (8,2) not null,
 StuffPriceTime datetime not null)

 insert into Stuff (StuffPrice, StuffSold, StuffPriceTime) values
 (10.0, 11.0, getdate()), --> lower
 (12.0, 11.0, getdate()), --> greater
 (17.0, 18.0, getdate()), --> lower
 (17.0, 16.0, getdate()); --> greater

Select
 StuffID,
 StuffPrice,
 StuffSold,
 StuffPriceTime,
 sum(case when StuffPrice > StuffSold then 1 else 0 end) over() [number of times]
From Stuff
```

Result:

```
StuffID StuffPrice  StuffSold   StuffPriceTime  [number of times]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       10.00       11.00       2015-01-01      2
2       12.00       11.00       2015-01-01      2
3       17.00       18.00       2015-01-01      2
4       17.00       16.00       2015-01-01      2
```